# Django. убрать дублирующиеся запросы - оптимизация запроса

Tags: python, django, for

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]> При запросе функции product.user_max из модели много дублирующихся запросов
Предполагаю что из за цикла
for person in cur:
Как можно сделать чтобы не было повторяющихся запросов.

```
from django_currentuser.middleware import (get_current_user, get_current_authenticated_user)

  
class DiscountMF(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Не действует'),
        (1, 'Действует'),
    )
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(ListUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='ID клиента')
    mf_id = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='ID бренда')
    k_up  = models.FloatField( verbose_name='Наценка к цене закупа')
    k_dn = models.FloatField(default=0,  verbose_name='Скидка к цене продажи')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False, blank=True, verbose_name='Обновляется')
    published = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='Опубликован')

    class Meta:
         ordering = ('client_id',)
         verbose_name = 'Индивиуальная скидка на производителя'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Индивиуальные скидки на производителя'
         unique_together = ('client_id', 'mf_id', )


    def mf_disc(self):
        if self.k_dn ==0:
            self.k_dn = 1
        return self.k_dn

    def client_mf(self):
        return self.client_id

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.k_dn}'
 

       class Product(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Не опубликовано'),
        (1, 'Опубликовано'),
    )
    id_p = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='ID продукта')
    artikul = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, verbose_name='Артикул')
    brend = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, verbose_name='Бренд для поиска')
    analog = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, verbose_name='Аналоги артикула')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products', verbose_name='Категория')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Бренд')
    product_sklad = models.ForeignKey(Sklad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, verbose_name='ID поставщика')
    product_time = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Срок доставки ( дн.)')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название продукции')
 description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    price = models.FloatField( verbose_name="Цена")
    zakup = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Цена закупа")
    discount_product_min = models.FloatField(default=0,
                                               verbose_name='Минимальный коэффициент скидки')
    price_magazin = models.FloatField( default=0, blank=True, verbose_name="Минимальная розничная цена")
    upakovka_f = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, verbose_name='Упаковка',
                                  help_text="Сколько единиц товара в упаковке")
    shtuk_e = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='Еденица измерения',
                               help_text="шт, компл, литр и т д ")
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Остаток на складе')
    stock_k13 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Количество товара в пути', blank=True)
    min_kol = models.IntegerField(default=1, db_index=True, verbose_name='Минимальное количество для покупки')
    new_product = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Новинка')
    published = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='опубликован')
    updated = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False, blank=True, verbose_name='Обновляется')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id_p'),)
        verbose_name = 'Продукт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'

#прайс с наценкой с учетом скидок и минимальной розничной цены
    def user_max(self):
        user = get_current_user()
        user_k = user.usrid.discount_list_k1.group_discount_list_k
        listusers_id = user.usrid.listusers_id
        cur = DiscountMF.objects.filter(mf_id=self.brand.brand_id, client_id=listusers_id).select_related('client_id', 'mf_id').values_list('k_dn', flat=True)
        post = []
        for person in cur:
            post.append(person)
        post1 = (" ".join(map(str, post)))
        if cur.exists():
            post1 = float(post1)
            if post1 == 1:
                post1 = 0
            if user_k == 0:
                user_k = 1
            user_max = max(post1, self.discount_product_min)
            price_user_max = float(user_max) * float(self.price)
            if self.price_magazin < price_user_max and self.price_magazin > 0:
                price_user_max = self.price_magazin
                return price_user_max
            else:
                return price_user_max
        else:
            if user_k == 0:
                user_k = 1
            user_max = max(user_k, self.discount_product_min)
            price_user_max = float(user_max) * self.price
            if self.price_magazin < price_user_max and self.price_magazin > 0:
                price_user_max = self.price_magazin
                return price_user_max
            else:
                return price_user_max
```